# mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, mysqli

im working on a website which mostly uses the database. the problem is that im geting the following error: `mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`
I cant figure out how to fix it. I've penta-checked the connect and it seems to be okay.

```
function connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
{
    $conid = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, TRUE);


    if($conid == FALSE)
    {
        if(DEBUG == TRUE)
        {
            show_error("MySQL Connection using `$hostname`, `$username`, `$password` was refused");
        }

        return;
    }

    else
    {
        $dbid = mysqli_select_db($database, $conid);

        if($dbid == FALSE)
        {
            if(DEBUG == TRUE)
            {
                show_error("MySQL could not connect to database `$database`");
            }

            return;
        }

        else
        {
            self::$connections[] = $conid;
            self::$connection    = $conid;
        }
    }
}
```

The code is writen in 2010 and then somehow it worked. Is it possible to fixit?

Answer (score 2):

It's the server hosting issue. You'd have to check with the hosting.

You can also read more tips at this link: http://albertech.net/2011/05/fix-php_network_getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service-not-known/

Comment: the other website is connecting to the same server and it hosted on the same machine.

Comment: Can you share the link?

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP server upgraded and your hosting didn't support it.

Comment: This is true with my case... My MySQL server was very old

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, My Issue was resolved by checking and resolving DNS resolution (in our case, the use in cagefs had different /etc/hosts than the core system)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across the error myself between 2 working PHP 7.1, Apache 2.4 & mariaDB 10.2/10.4 servers.

The issue for me was caused by using "http://1.2.3.4/" as the Database Host - this will cause PHP to return this error `mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known`.  For me this was of course some bogus error for me as they are both individually hosting the same websites & databases so there was no reason for it not to work.

The host variable should only be the IP address "1.2.3.4" or domain/subdomain (excluding the protocol) "example.com" or "subdomain.example.com" - which now connects correctly.