# Can't connect with database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm getting error after writing following code

```
<?php
$dbname = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "yangi";
$conn = new mysqli($dbname,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);

if($conn->connect_error){
    die("hatolik".$conn->connect_error);
}else{
    echo("success");
}
?>
```

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Yangi_korinish\inc\Connection.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������. in C:\xampp\htdocs\Yangi_korinish\inc\Connection.php on line 6
>   hatolikphp_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������.

Comment: what you mean there is only one connect function in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you used `$dbname` for the host name and the database name, which is *technically* being overwritten.

You need to change your code to the following:

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "yangi";
$conn = new mysqli($hostname,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$dbname);
```

Seeing the many `�`, you also have an encoding issue. Make everything to be UTF-8, which also includes the file's encoding.

Note: UTF-8 has a few encoding options. One to contain a BOM (byte order mark) or not. If that fails, you will need to make it "without" the BOM.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8
- [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

If the above statement failed, have a look at the following on Stack:

- [mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946763/mysqli-connect-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-service)

Which I doubt is a duplicate of this question. I have my money on the wrong hostname variable.

Comment: why was this downvoted? I'm not asking about the rep loss, I'm asking why a correct answer was downvoted.